# SQL Server 2008, JDO (Datanucleus 3.0.7) and column maximum length

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdo, datanucleus

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and the following jars are on my classpath:

```
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.6.jar
datanucleus-core-3.0.8.jar 
datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.1.jar 
datanucleus-rdbms-3.0.7.jar
```

I'd like to start with saying that everything works fine.

I persist successfully an object which has a String field that is supposed to contain an ASCII file content.

When the file is larger I get this error while persisting:

> javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Attempt to store value "|0|1.00|1.00|1.00||EUR
>   |8010312090196||ADVBANMMGM8|BA MASTER MGM 8|0|1.00|1.00|1.00||EUR
>   " in column "FILECONTENT" that has maximum length of 256. Please correct your data!

For the sake of clarity I trimmed down file content between quotation marks.

This is my package.jdo file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jdo PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Java Data Objects Metadata 2.0//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/jdo_2_0.dtd">
<jdo>
    <package name="com.mypackage.mycompany.model">

            <class name="FeedEvent" table="MY_UPLOADS" identity-type="application" >
                    <field name="id" persistence-modifier="persistent" primary-   key="true" value-strategy="identity" />
                    <field name="fileName" persistence-modifier="persistent" />
                    <field name="fileSize" persistence-modifier="persistent" />
                    <field name="fileContent" persistence-modifier="persistent"  />
                    <field name="uploaded" persistence-modifier="persistent" />
                    <field name="uploadDate" persistence-modifier="persistent" />
                    <field name="uploadFailureReason" persistence-modifier="persistent" />
                    <field name="eventDate" persistence-modifier="persistent" />
            </class>


    </package>
</jdo>
```

From windows code everything works fine and we're able to store files as big as 1MB so I guess is not related to DB type.

This is my POJO:

```
public class FeedEvent {

private Long id;
private String fileName;
private long fileSize;
private String fileContent;
private boolean uploaded;
private Date uploadDate;
private String uploadFailureReason;
private Date eventDate;

public FeedEvent() {
}

.......getters and setters here..............

}
```

Field `fileContent` is the one that gives problems when loaded with an ASCII file content. 
I tried to switch column type to `nvarchar(max)`, `text`, `varchar(max)` but no luck.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not leave things to "luck". The JDO spec has well defined ways of setting the length of a column; referring to any JDO book, or the documentation for DataNucleus would tell you clear enough about XML element `<column>` and would also tell you that `persistence-modifier="persistent"` is not needed for the vast majority of java field types

Comment: works now adding length attribute to column tag inside fileContent field. //Thanks